# How can I force only relative paths in "find" output?

Tags: linux, command-line, find, tar, recursive

I am attempting to create a script that can compress files with a certain extension in a number of directories into a single tar-ball. Currently what I have in the script file is:

```
find "$rootDir" -name '*doc' -exec tar rvf docs.tar {} \;
```

Where `$rootDir` is the base path to search.

This is fine except the paths are absolute in the tar file. I would prefer the paths to be relative to `$rootDir`. How would I go about doing this?

Example of current `tar -tf docs.tar` where `$rootDir` is `/home/username/test` output:

```
home/username/test/subdir/test.doc
home/username/test/second.doc
```

What I desire the output to be:

```
./subdir/test.doc
./second.doc
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you run `find` from the desired root directory and don't specify an absolute starting point in `find`'s options, it will output relative paths to the `tar` command invocations it constructs. Like so:

```
cd $rootDir
find . -name '*doc' -exec tar rvf docs.tar {} \;
```

If you do not want to change the current working directory permanently and are using `bash` or similar as your shell you could do

```
pushd $rootDir
find . -name '*doc' -exec tar rvf docs.tar {} \;
popd
```

instead.

Note that pushd/popd are not present in all shells, so check the man page as appropriate. They are present in bash but not in the base sh implementation so while explicitly using `/bin/bash` you can rely on them you can't if a script asks for `/bin/sh` instead (as this may map to a smaller shell that doesn't have bash's enhancements)

Comment: Or just use `cd $rootDir` and `cd -`  (at least in `bash`). `( cd $rootDir ; find ... )` would also be possible, i.e. doing everything in a subshell.

Answer (score 38):

You can use the `%P` format in the `-printf` directive:

```
find ${rootDir} -name '*.doc' -printf "%P\n"
```

will display in your example:

```
subdir/test.doc
second.doc
```

You may then use this `find` list in a `for` expression, in order to run our exec command, as in:

```
for f in $( find ${rootDir} -name '*.doc' -printf "%P\n" );
do
    tar rvf docs.tar ${f}
done
```

Comment: The accepted solution works but is is basically a hack. IMHO this should be the right solution to the question.

Comment: Thanks Narcolessico. It's also MHO :-)

Comment: I tried this but got the following error message:
`printf: %P: invalid conversion specification`